# form isValid() returns false when optional file elem. exists in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

in the controller isValid am facing problem.

```
if ($form->isValid($formdata))
```

This is my Code Zend_Form code

```
$document = $this->addElement('file','orglogo');
    $document = $this->getElement('orglogo')                    
                      ->removeDecorator('label')
                      ->addValidator('Extension', false, array('jpg,png,gif,jpeg'))
                      ->setRequired(true)
                      ->addErrorMessage('Please upload a valid File  (jpg,png,gif,jpeg)');
```

Its displaying error

File 'orglogo' exceeds the defined ini size

How can i solve this error.

---

Hurrrrrrrrrrrrrray!!!

Finally i got solution.

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Hope this will help someone.

Cheeeeeeeers,
Sathish

Comment: Why do you validate twice? Since the data is validated on input you do not need to validate it again when you read it from db. If I am wrong please edit you question and provide more information.

Comment: silly me i forgot to add enctype as well, small but crucial component when rendering the phtml view associated with form.

Answer (score 0):

If the form error arrays are empty then it might be a problem with setting the value of the elements from data.

Do the column names in couchdb match the names of the elements in the form? If not, then it probably isn't even trying to validate each element since assigning the elements their value is what is failing.

Comment: I am getting this error "File 'orglogo' exceeds the defined ini size".

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits the form the `$data['filename_element']` does not exists if the user didn't select any file, but if you take the database row you will always have an string of length 0 `$data['filename_element']`.

Do a `exit(var_dump($data));` on both the user supplied data and the database row and you will see the difference. 
P.S. `'filename_element'` needs to be replaced with the id of your file element.

Comment: When am submitting I am getting this error "File 'orglogo' exceeds the defined ini size". how can i solve this.